# Using indexPath.row to get an object from an array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How do i use indexPath.row to get an object from an array? I have tried with the following code but it returns "signal SIGABRT".. Please help

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *inde = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [inde integerValue]];
    int intrNum = [num intValue];
    NSString *name = [basket objectAtIndex:intrNum];


    cell.textLabel.text = name;
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    basket = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [basket addObject:@"1"];
    [self makeGrid];
 }


- (void)addToBasket:(id)sender {
    NSInteger prodID = ((UIControl*)sender).tag;

    [basket insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:prodID] atIndex:0];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Error message:

```
-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6866080 2012-05-05 02:29:18.208 app[7634:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6866080'
```

Comment: Are you sure `basket` is not nil?

Comment: yes. But it works when i run the app, but when i try to update the table by calling [self.tableView reloadData]; i get the SIGABRT

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use

```
NSString *name = [basket objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

?

Comment: well, it works when i run the app, but when i call [self.tableView reloadData]; it does not..

Comment: -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6866080
2012-05-05 02:29:18.208 app[7634:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6866080'

Comment: and also edit your question with the code where you instantiate you NSArray

Answer (score 1):

In `addToBasket` method you put `NSNumber` object into `basket` array, but in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you expect `NSString` objects in `basket`. To make your code working you can use safe conversion to string:

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[basket objectAtIndex:intrNum]];
```

Answer (score 0):

When your code

```
int intrNum = [num intValue];
```

the `intrNum` may is not real IndexPath Integer it may return the kind of address (example like '88792' or etc.) . So, It will cause problem with your array

Correct your get object from array code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

/* NSString *inde = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [inde integerValue]];
int intrNum = [num intValue]; */

NSString *name = [basket objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


cell.textLabel.text = name;
return cell;
```

}

and in the `addToBasket` you should not use `numberWithInt` like the reason about `int` that I've mentioned above.

```
- (void)addToBasket:(id)sender {
    NSInteger prodID = ((UIControl*)sender).tag;

    // [basket insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:prodID] atIndex:0];
    [basket insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:prodID] atIndex:0];    

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope it helps you!